# CSRFGuard and protecting links of pages sent out in emails

Tags: java, csrf, owasp

We implemented OWASP's CSRFGuard to protect our pages in the web application. For example */myCsrfProtected.jsp. We have injected CSRF token at all occurrences of */myCsrfProtected.jsp within the application. Everything works fine.

However, we have other use case where the link to this protected page is sent out to users in an email. Think about a link to a report. Now when user clicks on this link, the token is missing or invalid and hence the CSRFGuard filter blocks the request assuming this to be a CSRF attack. (this is what filter has been implemented for :-) )

Is there any way to handle this use case and allow access to CSRF protected page from outside the application.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a CSRF token check would need to performed only for POST requests. GET requests are supposed to be idempotent((no side effects on server, just return some data no transactions  performed on behalf of the user).

If all you want to do is return a report when the user clicks on link you might not need a csrf check to be performed. You might still want to make sure the user is authorised. You should be able to by pass the CSRF check for this request

Comment: **GET requests are supposed to be idempotent((no side effects on server**
Agreed
Unfortunately, my application uses GET requests to change server state. It is a pretty old application. Changing this would be a big task. So, we can't exclude GET requests from CSRF Validation.
Another problem is that the URL for creating reports and accessing reports is same. A request parameter distinguishes between both the actions. Again, this behavior can't be changed without significant cost.